# Anyone know function that is like Sin or Cos but with pointy tip?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

Basically like what the title saying, anyone know function that is like Sin or Cos but with pointy tip? 
[image of function that I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77QAj.png)

Edit:
There seems to be misunderstanding, since I can't draw it well on the image. I don't want it to be striped, but I want them to be connected line like Sin and Cos the only difference is just that the tip is pointy. 
[better image for the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esoQr.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "linear function"?

Comment: Such a function can't be linear, because it clearly does not look like a line.

Comment: I thought Sin Cos Tan is a linear function? it's not?

Comment: Something like this https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rvxomrjdml ? It is not one function but the delimitated area is similar (but not as well stripe separated as in your picture).

Comment: @zwim thanks it's indeed similar, but I need it to be connected

Comment: This comes in audio processing. You can do it by modulating a pre-existing function. For instance, something which looks like what you want is |x| * |sin(x)|. Now make the functio periodic by 2pi by definining it piecewise or smthn

Comment: graph:https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hwj4xnipvf

Comment: Raise $\sin$ to various positive integer powers and it will get more pointy.

Comment: You could add a sine function to a sawtooth function with the same zeros and tune the vertical parameters to get the kind of shape you want.

Answer (score 4):

Here is something from my initial idea based on $|\tan(x)|$ which presents the correct pointy shape.

[image]

Then I make the peaks alternated in sign by multiplying by a square signal $h$ (in blue)

$h(x)=\operatorname{sign}(\{\frac x2-\frac 14\}-\frac 12)\ $ and we graph $\ h(x)|\tan(\pi x)|$.

[image]

Then we need to offset the peaks vertically, this is simply done by adding an adjustable constant $b$

$f(x)=|\tan(\pi x)|-b\ $ and we graph $\ h(x)f(x)$.

[image]

But as you can notice there is quite a gap between the peaks. Note that since it is a function it CANNOT have a touching point, but we can make the curves close enough by deforming the shape.

We need to enlarge the stripes, this can be done by rasing to a power $n<1$, but if we are not careful, the shape will look like more a bracket $\Large{\{}$ than what we want.

For instance with $f(x)=|\tan(\pi x)|^n-b$ we get  for $n=0.3$ :

[image]

To remedy to this we want to raise to a power $q(x)$ which is close to $1$ around $0$ and smaller when get away from $0$. I tried different things and came up with $e^{-nx^2}$.

I need of course to make it periodic so in the end it is:

$p(x)=\{x-\frac 12\}-\frac 12\ $ and $\ q(x)=e^{-np(x)^2}$

And we graph for $f(x)=|\tan(\pi x)|^{q(x)}-b$

[image]

I think it is quite close to what you required, here is the Desmos page to play with the coefficients:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/y45pfma75v